# Applying common styles in angular

Tags: angular, sass

I am having styles that are common to two components in my angular application. Currently I have them applied in  scss files of the individual components. I have a root scss file called styles.scss

What is the best practice to make the styles common

The common styles are

```
h2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

form {
  margin: 15px;

  label {
    display: block;
  }

  input, select, button {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  small {
    color: red;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
  }
}

table {
  margin: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  th {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Styles.scss` is a common style file for reusability of css, just add all common styles to `styles.css` under any class name let's say `componentStyle`.

**Styles.css**

```
componentStyle{
// all common styles in here
}
```

Then in components add `componentStyle` to both component's parent div

**ComponentA.html**

```
<div class="componentStyle">
this is component A
<div>
```

**ComponentB.html**

```
<div class="componentStyle">
this is component B
<div>
```

Comment: Do i need to enclose the form in div or does my component style need to import or inherit style.scss .There would be some styles specific to each component as well

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two ways to achieve this -

1. You can add your common CSS code into the global CSS file as you mentioned in `stlyes.css` which exists on the Root level, generally all the common/shared styles to be written there which are being used in multiple components.
2. Create Module wise `style.css` file and `styleUrls` property in the component metadata accepts an array of files so you can mention there as well.

Styles specific to component level should be added in the component style files

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create wrapper on your already developed components, you can go a simple way by using the component's selectors as a wrapper in styles.scss

```
app-component-one, app-component-two {
  h2 {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

This will make sure that the component's styles don't bleed out. Also the components can have their own styles, in their own css files.